# Find the greatest possible value for $a+b+c+d$ if $b > 0$ and $a,b,c$ and $d$ satisfy the system of equations $a+b=c,b+c=d, c+d=a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the greatest possible value for $a+b+c+d$ if $b$ is a postive integer and $a,b,c,$ and $d$ satisfy the system of equations
\begin{align*}
a+b &= c, \\
b+c &= d, \\
c+d &= a.
\end{align*}

The problem proivdes the hint: Find each of the variables in terms of $b$.

So,
\begin{align*}
a &= -b + c, \tag{1}\\
c &= -b + d, \tag{2}\\
d & = b + c. \tag{3}
\end{align*}

Can I set up the System of equations as above? I derive equations $2$ and $3$ from the same equation. When I try to reduuce the system to one involving just three variables things become quite confusing.

On another note since the system of equations has four variables and only three equations, does this mean there are infinetly many soultions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

The sum of the three equations of your first system gives

$$2b+c=0$$

Using the expressions you found, we get

$$a=c-b=-3b$$
$$d=b+c=-b$$

So

$$a+b+c+d=-3b+b-2b-b$$
$$=-5b$$

Comment: The greatest value would then be $-5$ when $b=1$?

Comment: @Edmund Yes. If $ b=1$ then $a=-3,c=-2,d=-1$